# Why does `route` hang for a while before the route table being dumped?

Tags: shell-script, gateway, routing

Typing the command:

```
% route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
(... hang for a while ...)
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

Here, before the last line `default` rule be printed, route just hang for while.

Isn't the route table cached somewhere?

I used to grep the result from `route` to get the `default` rule, to get the default gateway. Now, `route` seems hang for a while in some machines.

Comment: BTW, it would be more efficient to parse the /proc/net/route file for that information.

Comment: The IPs are encoded in hex numbers in `/proc/net/route`.

Comment: Yes. so you can convert them. If you can't, the output of `ip route` is also easier to parse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's trying to do a reverse DNS lookup on the gateway address, and waiting for timeout. Try running with the `-n` option to suppress that.

Answer (score 3):

You may have some DNS related problems. Try the following to check it out:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver <IP_1>
nameserver <IP_2>
search <DOMAIN>

host www.google.com <IP_1>

host www.google.com <IP_2>
```

If everything is working fine, you shouldn't get any delays while executing 'route' command

Regards